# import custom logging module throws error

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I test following code to understand importing a custom python program and it works fine but when follow same process for importing custom logging module I see error.

**Below works fine**

```
#calculation.py
from mult import product
def add(a,b):
    return a + b
if __name__== '__main__':
    a = 10
    b = 5
    print(add(a,b))
    print(product(a,b))
```

Now second program mult.py

```
# mult.py
def product(a,b):
return a * b
```

**Below does not work, why?**

```
#test_logger.py
import loggerforhousing
print("custom logs")
logger.info("this is info")
logger.error("this is error")
```

**second program**

```
#loggerforhousing.py
import logging    

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('train_123.log') # store log files in artifacts directory
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_logger.py", line 3, in <module>
    logger.info("this is info")
NameError: name 'logger' is not defined
```

Please help me figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

In **test_logger.py**, declare logger as being part of **loggerforhousing.py**:

```
loggerforhousing.logger.info(“this is info”)
```

Or import logger explicitly (as done in your first snippet with product function):

```
from loggerforhousing import logger
```

Does it help?

Comment: it works and I know my mistake... all because of late night coding :-)